# What happens when an invalid argument is fed to uuid.UUID()?

Tags: python, exception, uuid

Will an exception get thrown? Does UUID() ever silently fail? Is there ANY circumstance in which 'myStatus' from

```
myStatus = True
myUUID = uuid.UUID( someWeirdValue )
if myUUID == None:
    myStatus = False
```

would equal False?

Comment: This kind of things can be checked easly by oneself, mate. Just go to python interpreter and execute this snippet, don't ask like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `UUID()` constructor either raises a `TypeError` or a `ValueError`, depending on what was passed in.

Not passing in any of the `hex`, `bytes`, `bytes_le`, `fields`, or `int` options raises a `TypeError`, passing in a value that is invalid raises a `ValueError`:

```
>>> uuid.UUID()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/uuid.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise TypeError('need one of hex, bytes, bytes_le, fields, or int')
TypeError: need one of hex, bytes, bytes_le, fields, or int
>>> uuid.UUID('abcd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/uuid.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
>>> uuid.UUID(bytes='abcd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/uuid.py", line 144, in __init__
    raise ValueError('bytes is not a 16-char string')
ValueError: bytes is not a 16-char string
```

etc.

It will *not* fail silently. It'll certainly never return `None`. Either `myUUID` is set to a `UUID` instance, or an exception is raised.

Comment: What about the second part of my question? Is there any circumstance which 'myStatus' would equal False?

Comment: @yourfriendzak: No, because you either get a `UUID` instance, or it raises an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`UUID` class](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cfc777407b03/Lib/uuid.py#l53) doesn't override `__new__`, there is no way that its construction can return anything other than an `uuid.UUID` instance.

UUID factories provided by the module, the functions `uuid1` through `uuid4`, could conceivably have a bug that causes them to return `None`. Judging by a cursory glance at their [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cfc777407b03/Lib/uuid.py#l490), such a bug does not appear likely. Whatever fault is causing your UUID objects to be `None`, the `uuid` module is not a credible culprit.

Comment: The convenience methods most certainly all return `UUID` instances, or raise an exception. There is no chance any of those would return `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed, but one has to study the code of each of them to be sure. On the other hand, construction is in the clear by the very fact that the class doesn't define `__new__` (or specify a metaclass).

Comment: That is what I did; the functions are simple enough. I *am* sure. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The point of my distinct answer was to show to the OP that he doesn't need to try to pass different weird values to be sure he's not getting `None`—he can *know* that just from the look of the constructor. May not make a huge difference in this case, but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: Yup, understood that part, just adding an assurance that the convenience functions will not return `None` either. Ever.